# Kazam webcam is black / not working

Tags: webcam, screencast, kazam

kazam `1.5.3`
ubuntu `16.04.2 LTS xenial`

screen recording works fine, but adding the webcam just adds a black square in the top right corner, which I can move with `alt + click & drag`

If I do a webcam ONLY recording (no screen), and then hit "finish recording", it just stops recording and there's no prompting to save the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

### About Webcam:

I had the same issue that it was showing a black square in the top right corner. But then I played with some of the settings in [File -> Preferences -> Webcam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNlDN.png) settings [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDkOa.png).

Now, if you'll try recording from webcam then it might work fine.

### Saving the file:

[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDkOa.png) under File -> Preferences -> Webcam, you have an option to Save files automatically which you can turn on.

Comment: I don't see a way to save preferences. Did you change via  config file or gui itself?